# AnyMail and MailGun configuration on Django

Tags: python, django, mailgun, django-anymail

I'm setting AnyMail + MailGun on a Django project, but I'm getting an unauthorized response calling `mail_admins`:

`anymail.exceptions.AnymailRequestsAPIError: Sending a message to mail@gmail.com from mailgun@sandboxe6301378bfe741bf99d5684e65852283.mailgun.org Mailgun API response 401 (Unauthorized): 'Forbidden'`

These are my `settings.py` configs:

```py
EMAIL_BACKEND = "anymail.backends.mailgun.EmailBackend"

ANYMAIL = {
    "MAILGUN_API_KEY": os.environ.get("MAILGUN_API_KEY"),
    "MAILGUN_API_URL": "https://api.mailgun.net/v3",
    "MAILGUN_SENDER_DOMAIN": "sandboxe6301378bfe741bf99d5684e65852283.mailgun.org"),
}

SERVER_EMAIL = "mailgun@sandboxe6301378bfe741bf99d5684e65852283.mailgun.org"
# SERVER_EMAIL = "mail@gmail.com"
# DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "mail@gmail.com"

ADMINS = [("Admin", "mail@gmail.com"), ]
```

I'm able to send emails w/ these configs w/ CURL. I must be missing something on Django settings.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I also copied the `api:` prefix from the CURL snippet to the `MAILGUN_API_KEY` variable, and I wasn't passing `DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = "mailgun@sandboxe6301378bfe741bf99d5684e65852283.mailgun.org"`, hence the error.